# C++ - Using specific character input for 'if' statements

Tags: c++, key

I am, for lack of a better word, an absolute programming novice. And as it stands, I've been flung head first into programming something in two or three languages.

As part of an assignment, we have been tasked with essentially recreating a heads/tails flip, in the form of a random chance game.
The way it works is the player has ten credits to start off with. They are asked to input a wager, and then they are asked heads or tails. Picking either heads or tails sets off a number generator, and depending on the value, they may well end up winning or losing their wager.

I coded a similar version of this using HTML/CSS/JS, and it works. I'll leave a puush link to the file so you can view it yourselves to get an idea of what I'm trying to do: http://puu.sh/bP2V7/2ef63f4a1c.html

I'm trying to do, functionally, the same thing in C++ in the form of a command application. I know the code I'm using works fine, and it compiles without much of a hitch. It's a bit annoying that it closes down rather than resetting to a previous line, but that's a hurdle I'll jump over when I get to it.

I had a look around, and to be honest, whilst a few of the things may well work, I'm admittedly relatively clueless and some of the programmer speak kinda flies over my head.

It's probably because I'm being thrown into it and I'm not used to it yet, but as it stands, I need your help.

My code simply works as follows (simplified to save time):

```
int main()
{
    int points, wager;
    points = 10;
    output "HEADS OR TAILS?";

    if (player has 1 point or more)
    {
        output "Input wager";
        input wager value;
        output "Wager is (player input)";
        output "Heads or Tails?";
        input h or t;                      //This was what I wanted

        if (player selects 'heads')        //For sake of simplicity, the code
        {                                  //here will account for both heads
            int heads;                     //and tails.
            srand(NULL);
            heads = random number 1 and 2;
            if (heads = 1)
            {
                output "HEADS!";
                output "You win 'wager'!";
                points = points + wager;
            }
            if (heads = 2)
            {
                output "TAILS!";
                output "You lose 'wager'!";
                points = points - wager;
            }
        }
    }
    if (player has 0 points)
    {
        output "GAME OVER";
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have the user input either an 'h' or a 't' to determine whether or not they want heads or tails.

Comment: I'm out of close votes today, but I'm pretty sure this one applies to your question: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As it stands, show us your code and where it's not doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: Please add your code.  There are very limited cases when anybody's going to be willing to follow a link to read your code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. On this site you are encouraged to avoid long rambling background stories and introductions. Instead, stick to the specifics of the question. I have edited your question so you can see what I mean. However, the question is still likely to be closed as you are expected to show the code for your attempt (i.e. the C++ attempt), and properly describe what is wrong with it or where you are stuck (e.g. expected vs actual behaviour, error message, etc.). You are also expected to have done research. In your case, that means reading an introductory C++ book before asking here.

Comment: @JBentley Just taking this action, instead of letting the OP doing this, is contra-productive IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Edits are meant to improve the question, not help the OP learn the ropes of the site. The latter was merely a bi-product of my edit. The question is now more readable and doesn't require third party links.

Comment: @JBentley I respect that I'm meant to avoid rambling, but I only need to know how to utilise character specific input, not just "how do I port this to C++". In the text you cut, I provided context and stated what it was I wanted, but you removed the point of the question, which was "how do I utilise character-specific input in C++".

Comment: @JBentley I rolled back your edits, that was just a radical change of the original post. If you meant to replace the link with code, just replace that link, but don't vandalize the question!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To suggest that I vandalised the question is extreme, to say the least. The OP's complaint (about utilising character specific input) is in the title, which I left unmodified. You'd be better off improving the question further than reverting it back to the current version IMO. But ultimately it's pointless arguing over a post which should be closed anyway.

Comment: @JBentley There was an answer to my question. The answer provided helped solve my problem. My question didn't need any code, because I was asking for code in the first place. How can I show code if the specific code didn't exist before I asked this question? My intention here was to find out how to do a certain thing, not to have my code checked over. You completely stripped back the question and turned it to its raw form, rather than cut down the stuff that didn't need to be. So, just think about that for a sec.

Comment: @DanielLearmouth You are new to the site. You can see your question has 4 downvotes. What you don't see is that it also has 4 close votes. Questions asking "how do I do X?" without any research effort and/or attempt, are off-topic. Your question is also unclear - you allude to code you have already written, but now you claim none exists. Being concise and sticking to the point would help with this. I suggest you review the help sections which are linked at the top for further guidance.

Comment: @JBentley I stand by what I said. I said that I had difficulty comprehending other places. That is the reason I asked this question in the first place. I did put some time and effort into researching, so claiming the opposite would be a lie. Besides, the code that I provided was for a different language that utilised a GUI, not command line. Surely you understand, right?

Comment: @DanielLearmouth The confusion lies in this statement: *"I'm trying to do, functionally, the same thing in C++ in the form of a command application. I know the code I'm using works fine, and it compiles without much of a hitch."*. HTML/CSS/JS isn't compiled, and C++ is, so presumably you have some C++ code. Note that I'm only posting these comments to try to help you for your future questions - this particular question is closed now so the point is really moot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your programming class, they will have told you what they expect you to use as tools for input and output, eg `char inputChar; cin >> inputChar;` or similar.  Use whatever they told you to use in the style they want you to use, eg

```
cout << HEADS_OR_TAILS_PROMPT;
char inputChar;
cin >> inputChar;
switch(inputChar) {
  case 'h':
  {
    ... // code for the heads case
    break;
  }
  case 't':
  {
    ... // code for the tails case
    break;
  }
  default:
    // whatever you want to do if they didn't input a valid option
}
```

Although, to be honest, asking your professor is going to get you a better answer for what the grader is expecting than asking us is.

Comment: I would appreciate suggestions on how to improve this answer if you think there's significant issues with it, rather than a meaningless downvote.

Comment: Teaching the OP the full syntax of a switch statement seems out of the scope of this question, but I see your point so I added them in, thanks!

And I agree that the question is not particularly addressable, which is why the answer is pretty broad.

Comment: As it stands, this has worked for me. Thanks, man. You've saved me a heck of a runaround.

Comment: No problem.  Getting started with a new language (especially a new type of language) can be overwhelming.  Hopefully it goes well for you.  Good luck!